# How to use Lucene ShingleFilter: Could not find implementing class for org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute

Tags: hadoop, lucene, n-gram

Code is here: [github link](https://github.com/rjurney/datafu/blob/lucene/src/java/datafu/pig/text/lucene/NGramTokenize.java)

Error is:

ren: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementing class for org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:338)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:282)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementing class for org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute

at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource$AttributeFactory$DefaultAttributeFactory.getClassForInterface(AttributeSource.java:94)

at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource$AttributeFactory$DefaultAttributeFactory.createAttributeInstance(AttributeSource.java:67)

at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource.addAttribute(AttributeSource.java:276)

at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.(StandardTokenizer.java:171)

at datafu.pig.text.lucene.NGramTokenize.exec(NGramTokenize.java:48)

at datafu.pig.text.lucene.NGramTokenize.exec(NGramTokenize.java:33)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextDataBag(POUserFunc.java:374)

at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:309)

... 9 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a packaging issue. When building datafu I did not find `o.a.lucene.analysis.tokenatributes.OffsetAttributeImpl` in the `datafu-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Lucene's AttributeSource [finds implementations for attribute classes at runtime](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_3_6_2/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/AttributeSource.java#L94), so it's necessary to package `o.a.lucene.analysis.tokenatributes.OffsetAttributeImpl` in the `datafu-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in addition to the `o.a.lucene.analysis.tokenatributes.OffsetAttribute` class.

You will likely run into this problem with other attribute classes as well.

From what I understand autojar is explicitly following class references at compile time in order to determine what goes in the final jar. This is why it's not picking up the attribute Impl classes, which are resolved at runtime.

I'm not sufficiently familiar with autojar to suggest a fix but if there is a way to explicitly include classes, you should include `org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.*Impl`